# None of your spec sources contain a spec satisfying the dependency

Tags: swift, cocoapods, podspec

I am referencing the pod 'MatomoTracker' in my own pod
I get this error while linting : with `pod lint spec`

```
 -> TrackerPod.v3 (0.0.1)
    - ERROR | [iOS] unknown: Encountered an unknown error (CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "Pods/MatomoTracker/MatomoTracker":
  In Podfile:
    TrackerPod.v3 (from `/Users/****/Documents/projects/ios/libs/TrackerPod.v3/TrackerPod.v3.podspec`) was resolved to 0.0.1, which depends on
      TrackerPod.v3/Matomo (= 0.0.1) was resolved to 0.0.1, which depends on
        Pods/MatomoTracker/MatomoTracker (= 5.2.0)

None of your spec sources contain a spec satisfying the dependency: `Pods/MatomoTracker/MatomoTracker (= 5.2.0)`.

You have either:
 * out-of-date source repos which you can update with `pod repo update` or with `pod install --repo-update`.
 * mistyped the name or version.
 * not added the source repo that hosts the Podspec to your Podfile.

Note: as of CocoaPods 1.0, `pod repo update` does not happen on `pod install` by default.) during validation.

Analyzed 1 podspec.

[!] The spec did not pass validation, due to 1 error.
```

this is my **podspec**:

```
Pod::Spec.new do |spec|

  spec.name         = 'TrackerPod.v3'
  spec.version      = '0.0.1'
  spec.license      = 'Copyright ****'
  spec.homepage     = 'https://*******8/TrackerPod/blob/master/README.md'
  spec.author       = { '****' => '****@****.com' }
  spec.summary      = 'Some description'
  spec.source       = { :git => '****', :tag => spec.version.to_s }
  spec.source_files  = 'TrackerPod.v3/*.{h,m, swift}'
  spec.ios.deployment_target = '8.0'
  spec.osx.deployment_target = '10.10'
  spec.requires_arc = true
  spec.swift_version = '4.0'
  spec.xcconfig = { 'SWIFT_VERSION' => '4.1' }
  spec.dependency 'MatomoTracker', '5.2.0'
  spec.subspec 'Matomo' do |lib|
    lib.dependency 'Pods/MatomoTracker/MatomoTracker', '5.2.0'
    lib.source_files = 'Pods/MatomoTracker/MatomoTracker/**/*.{h,m,swift}'
  end
end
```

and, this is **a screenshot** to show my project navigator.
You can see that MatomoTracker is nested 2 levels downs inside 'Pods'

[the project navigator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EQofs.png)

Am using the right path to reference MatomoTracker `Pods/MatomoTracker/MatomoTracker`, it does not seem to find the pod Matomoto ?
Am I correct ?

Comment: `lib.dependency 'Pods/MatomoTracker/MatomoTracker', '5.2.0'` => `lib.dependency 'MatomoTracker', '5.2.0'`? No need to specify its path.

Comment: I posted an answer. still in the dark though

Answer (score 0):

to answer the question. I kind of know where the error stands.
In my podspec, I am using spec.dependency `'MatomoTracker', '~> 5.2'`

without the above the line, the validation passes
it seems that a higher minimum deployment target is required. I have update to **deployment target as 11.0** everywhere.
- Podfile
- build settings (pod target) in Xcode
- spec ios target as well in the pod spec

and, this is the error I get

```
ERROR | [iOS] xcodebuild: Returned an unsuccessful exit code. You can use `--verbose` for more information.

ERROR | [OSX] unknown: Encountered an unknown error (CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "MatomoTracker":
  In Podfile:
    TrackerPod.v3 (from `/Users/*****/Documents/projects/ios/libs/TrackerPod.v3`) was resolved to 0.0.1, which depends on
      MatomoTracker (~> 5.2)

Specs satisfying the `MatomoTracker (~> 5.2)` dependency were found, but they required a higher minimum deployment target.) during validation.
```

Although I feel like I did by the book and as per the [cocoapods guide](https://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podspec.html), I am still missing sthg.
The **MatomoTracker** does not pass the validation